# Puppeteer - string is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

Everytime I pass an xpath to my function it returns  `string is not a valid XPath expression`. Why is that?

```
const searchSelector = '//*table/tbody/tr/td[1]';

const result = await page.evaluate(element => {
      return element.textContent;
    }, await page.$x(searchSelector));
```

[image: html]

Comment: Consider using an XPath engine that gives better diagnostics. oXygen for example gives "Unexpected token name "table" beyond end of expression" which at least points you to the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is not a valid XPath, consider this XPath:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

or if you need to rely on `class` name:

```
//table[@class = 'classname']/tbody/tr/td[1]
```